# React gives a 301 error with inline functions but not with inline anonymous ones

Tags: reactjs, state, use-state, anonymous-function, inline-functions

This code generates a *React* error 301: https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=301

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

return <>
    <p>{count}</p>
    <button onClick={setCount(count + 1)} >Increment count by 1</button>
</>
```

But if I run the `setCount` function inside a *anonymous function* I does not:

```
return <>
   <p>{count}</p>
    <button
        onClick = {() => {
            setCount(count + 1)
        }} 
    >Increment count by 1</button>
</>
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Since setCount is called within the onClick function, this causes the state value to constantly change and rerender. You must assign the function inside the onClick function to a function. as in second use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, every time the component renders it calls `setCount` (`onClick` is set to the return value of `setCount(count + 1)`). This call triggers a re-render. This is why you get that error.

In the second case the call to `setCount` is deferrred until the button is clicked, thus not leading to a re-render on every render.

Comment: But shouldn’t the function inside onClick only run on on click, anonymous or inline?

Comment: In the first case you aren't passing a function, but the result of calling a function. e.g. it's the difference between `const onClick = myFunc()` and `const onClick = myFunc`